# Set default focus when 'If' binding expression turns true

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I have a form with the 'If' binding applied and some input controls in it. So it looks similar to this:

```
<form data-bind="if: MyExpression">
   <input id="input1" class="autofocus"></input>
   <input id="input2"></input>
   <input id="input3"></input>
</form>
```

Now, I want to set focus on the input with the 'autofocus' class whenever 'MyExpression' turns true and the form shows up on screen.
Any Ideas how to achieve that?

I tried this so far:

```
this.MyExpression.subscribe(function (isTrue) {
    if (isTrue) {
        $('.autofocus').focus();
    }
});
```

but that didn't work.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`hasfocus` binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/hasfocus-binding.html) on your first input:

```
<form data-bind="if: MyExpression">
   <input id="input1" data-bind="hasfocus: true"></input>
   <input id="input2"></input>
   <input id="input3"></input>
</form>
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/44wYG/).